# Getting an error setting up GrovePi with Node-Red

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi3, node-red, grovepi+

I have been trying to set up GrovePi to be coded with Node-Red, but am getting an error. I can download all of the files, but get a warning upon loading node-red:

[grovepi] SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

And the nodes for GrovePi are not shown. I can see in my Palette Manager that I have the grove pi contrib node installed but none of them are activated (circle next to the node is not filled with a color.) Any ideas how to solve this? I have also installed node-grovepi as that was said to be a dependency.﻿

If I install node-red-contrib-grovepi in the pallette manager of Node-Red, I can see the nodes show up in the side menu, but if I refresh the page they disappear.

Comment: What version of node.js are you using? If you search for that specific error you'll find lots of results referencing using an old version of node.js.

Comment: My nodejs is v4.8.2, which is shown to be the most current and the problem still occurs

Comment: Node 6.x is the current LTS version of node and should address that issue.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you, I am quite new at this.